# How to optimize this MySQL routines

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Using MySQL 5.7.22

Run pt-query-digest on slow query log

```
 # Query 6: 0.00 QPS, 0.00x concurrency, ID 0x5863FD9F47316C48AE1FBD931F05AA56 at byte 9577338
# Scores: V/M = 2.36
# Time range: 2018-10-13T05:18:14 to 2018-11-27T02:05:07
# Attribute    pct   total     min     max     avg     95%  stddev  median
# ============ === ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= =======
# Count          1      33
# Exec time      1    145s      1s     13s      4s      8s      3s      2s
# Lock time      2   432us       0   168us    13us   113us    41us       0
# Rows sent      0  14.72k       3     890  456.79  874.75  391.41  112.70
# Rows examine   2  38.76M 171.32k   1.42M   1.17M   1.39M 387.45k   1.20M
# Query size     0  30.27k     127   2.27k  939.21   1.53k  727.48   1.46k
# String:
# Hosts        13.186.31.88 (16/48%), HKGNB16120... (14/42%)... 2 more
# Users        root
# Query_time distribution
#   1us
#  10us
# 100us
#   1ms
#  10ms
# 100ms
#    1s  ################################################################
#  10s+  ####
```

This is my routine code https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/gky7Ec-Ws4baikNp1oTjtw

I run the routine and here is the profiles

```
mysql> show profiles;
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query
                                                                                                                               |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        3 | 9.70020200 | select
                t.id, t.DelegationID
        , case when (select count(lbl.id) from `labels` as lbl where lbl.ObjectID = t.id and lbl.ObjectName = 'tasks' and lbl.ColumnName = 'TaskName' and lbl.LanguageCode = p_language and lbl.IsDelete
d = 0) > 0 then
                        (select content from `labels` as lbl where lbl.Obje |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

It has run for 10 seconds, how can I improve this routine?

Comment: need `show create table {tablename}` from the tables involved and `explain {query}` output. `p_locationIDs is null or p_locationIDs = ''` normalise what an empty item is and then avoid `or` conditions. Only use `LEFT JOIN` when you want the missing RHS. `FIND_IN_SET` is slow ([list of doom](http://gtowey.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-fix-comma-separated-list-of-doom.html)).

Comment: Thanks @danblack. Can you tell more on `p_locationIDs is null or p_locationIDs = '' normalise what an empty item is`

Comment: This expression on its own can't use an index. As such your application should decide if `NULL` means empty or `""` means empty. Once that is normalized the query can eliminate a criteria. Which one you use isn't particularly important, just choose one.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  ara.ApprovalStatus
    from  `approval_request_approvers` as ara
    where  ara.ApprovalRequestID = rt.ApprovalRequestID
      and  ara.IsDeleted = 0
    order by  ara.ModifiedDate desc
    limit  1
```

is executed in 7 places.  See if you can make it only once.

And it could use

```
INDEX(IsDeleted, ApprovalRequestID,  -- in either order for WHERE
      ModifiedDate,                  -- 3rd; for ORDER BY
      ApprovalStatus)                -- for "covering"
```

You have some `LEFT JOINs`.  Could the be changed to `JOIN`?

Change from

```
or
            (
                select count(*) 
                from ...
            ) > 0
```

to

```
or EXISTS ( SELECT * from ... )
```

For this:

```
p_createdBy is null or p_createdBy = ''
```

Consider deciding on `NULL` or `''`, then sticking with it.  This gets rid of one `OR`.

Any place where you use `OR`, see if you can reformulate the query.

Testing against `NULL` always fails in inequalities, so

```
(p_createdDateFrom is not null and p_createdDateFrom <= t.CreatedDate)
```

-->

```
p_createdDateFrom <= t.CreatedDate
```

The main `WHERE` has at least 11 tests `AND'd` together.  Are all of them TRUE most of the time?  If not, then rearrange them so that the most likely to fail are first.

Rather than passing in NULL/blank for things you don't want tested, have your client software construct the query with just the things you *do* want tested.  *Then* we could discuss other options for indexes.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to discuss further.